# Insert an HTML heading on each pages in a while PHP for print

Tags: printing, page-break

My question is a bit hard to explain but there I go..

I have a document generated in a WHILE (php) from a MySQL request and it does ~ 10 pages when I press Ctrl+P.

**Demo source : http://3ansdemulti.com/dev/print.htm**

As you can see, I would like to know if it is possible to configure dynamics pages with the HEADER on top of each PRINT page..

I know I can use the page-break-before on the element but how could I know how to determine where the page should break?

If you need more information, just ask me! I am open to discussions.

Comment: I would do this with fPDF instead, and generate nice easily emailable PDF files   http://www.fpdf.org/    Heres a demo of the header footer function... http://www.fpdf.org/en/tutorial/tuto2.php

Answer (score 0):

Use fPDF....

```
<?php
 require('fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
// Logo
$this->Image('logo.png',10,6,30);
// Arial bold 15
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
// Move to the right
$this->Cell(80);
// Title
$this->Cell(30,10,'Title',1,0,'C');
// Line break
$this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
 // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
 $this->SetY(-15);
 // Arial italic 8
 $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
 // Page number
 $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
}
}

//YOUR LOOP GOES HERE AND DEPENDING ON HOW MANY ITEMS FIT ON A PAGE, 
//YOU ADD NEW PAGE...AND CALL THE HEADER AND FOOTER EACH TIME....
//DOCUMENTATION CAN BE      FOUND ON THE SITE...

?>
```

www.fpdf.org

Just download the library and give it a go, it's the way better option for printable/emailable documents.

Comment: Thx for the link! I will check this tonight and give you feedbacks!

Comment: I there anyway to place custom HTML ?

Comment: I don't think so, but its just a matter of learning the API for it, and using it.  What you show in your example is quite easy to do in fPDF